# Show that it is a subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

To show that $$\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/x}, 2^{1/y}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/{xy}})$$ knowing that $(x,y)=1$, $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$ can we do the following??

$$2^{\frac{1}{x}}=2^{\frac{y}{xy}}=\left ( 2^{\frac{1}{xy}} \right )^y \in \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/{xy}})$$

$$2^{\frac{1}{y}}=2^{\frac{x}{xy}}=\left ( 2^{\frac{1}{xy}} \right )^x \in \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/{xy}})$$

Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/x}, 2^{1/y}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/{xy}})$.

Is this correct??

Comment: What's $x$ and $y$? Positive integers?

Comment: $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: It seems correct.

Comment: Nice!!! Thanks!!! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed correct.

Nevertheless, you have not used the condtion $(x,y)=1$. In fact, you do not need it, as 
$$
\mathbb Q(2^{1/x},2^{1/y})\subset\mathbb Q(2^{1/xy}),
$$
even in the case when $x$ and $y$ are not relatively prime.

Comment: Great!!! Thank you!!! :-)